# Angle between two planes

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm hoping that this is an easy problem.

I have a vector which is normal to a plane in 3D space. What I want to do is find the angle of this plane relative to a plane parallel to the y axis.

The problem is I have a 4 sided pyramid [image]

[image: Top View]

When looking from the top I want to find the angle between the surface normal and the Y axis. So for this example it should be 135 degrees or 45 degrees depending on direction. The points of the triangle are (-49.49747, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, -49.49747, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 70.0) and the surface normal is (-0.6324555, -0.6324555, 0.4472136).

This is for a project I am working on and I can get it working when the faces of the object are vertical, but once there are 3D involved my formulas don't work and I'm not sure what exactly I need to do to get the correct answer.

Any help would be great.

Thanks
Nick

Comment: Which plane do you want? There are infinitely many planes parallel to the $y$-axis.

Comment: The one running along the y axis. Where the arrow is in the second picture. Forgot to specify sorry.

Comment: The $xy$ plane and the $yz$ plane, among others, are parallel to the $y$ axis. I'm not sure which you want.

Comment: to be honest I'm not really sure. Basically I'm looking at this as a 2D problem. If looking from the top I want to find the angle between the arrow coming from the blue face (the surface normal), and the arrow pointing along the Y axis. The answer should be either 135 or 45 degrees. I just can't work out a formula to use to solve this.

Comment: Oh, okay. You know that $|u||v| \cos \theta = u \cdot v$, so you can find the angle by computing $\arccos \frac{u \cdot v}{|u||v|}$, where $u$ is the surface normal, and $v$ is $\langle 0,1,0 \rangle$

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work for me. Using the example above I get an angle of 129 degrees when I know it should be 135 degrees. The problem is that the surface normal of the selected face has a z component.

Comment: Oh! Now I get what you want! You want to flatten the vector into the $xy$ plane, then get the angle, right? Then just make the $z$ component of $u$ be $0$. So for an explicit formula: $\theta = \arccos \frac{u' \cdot v}{|u'||v|} = \arccos \frac{u_x v_x + u_y v_y}{\sqrt{u_x^2 + u_y^2}\sqrt{v_x^2 + v_y^2}} = \arccos \frac{u_y}{\sqrt{u_x^2 + u_y^2}}$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know I could just set the z component to zero. If you post this as an answer I will mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Was a comment, is now an answer)

You want to flatten the vector into the $xy$ plane, then get the angle, right? Then just make the $z$ component of $u$ be $0$. So for an explicit formula:
$$\theta = \arccos \frac{u' \cdot v}{|u'||v|} = \arccos \frac{u_x v_x + u_y v_y}{\sqrt{u_x^2+u_y^2}\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}} = \arccos \frac{u_y}{u_x^2 + u_y^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

For any plane, you can find a *normal vector* for that plane. In particular, if a plane is given by $ax + by + cz + d = 0$, then $(a,b,c)$ is a normal vector for that plane. Then, to find the angle between any two planes, you merely need to calculate the angle between their normal vectors. So suppose we have two planes $P_1, P_2$, and they have normal vectors $n_1, n_2$. Then the angle $\theta$ between them can be calculate according to the inner product formula

$$ n_1 \cdot n_2 = \| n_1 \| \|n_2\| \cos{\theta} $$
where $n_1 \cdot n_2 = a_1 a_2 + b_1 b_2 + c_1 c_2$ if $n_i = (a_i, b_i, c_i)$, and $\|n_i\| = \sqrt{a_i^2 + b_i^2 + c_i^2}$.

This method generalizes to hyperplanes (codimension 1) for arbitrarily many dimensions.

Comment: That is what I have used previously however for my application it doesn't do what I need. I need to rotate that part so that the bottom edge of the triangle is perpendicular to the y axis. By using that method I get an answer of about 50 degrees. However I need it to be either 45 or 135 degrees.